Modal verbs used in the past

You should do that when she came

You should have done it when she came

You should do that before she came

You should have done it before she came

You should do that after she came

You should have done it after she came


1 means that something should be done after her arrival and 2 before.    Let's now consider 3 and 4.    To me both are fine and mean the same thing.    Now 5 and 6. I think 5 is okay but 6 I'm not sure about it.
To sum up: I'm sure that my understanding of 1 and 2 is correct. I don't know what about the rest. Can you tell me if they make sense?

Only 2, 4 and 6 make sense. You can't recommend an action in relation to another action which has already happened. 1, 3 and 5 require comes.

@KateBunting . Let me present different examples. If you say "I suggested that she should have bought a car", this means that you suggested that she should (already) have bought a car (by the time you spoke).
But if you say "I suggested that she should buy a car", then the possibility of buying one was still open to her at the time you spoke to her. I thought my examples 1 and 2 worked the same way. Does it change anything if I add "I thought" before my 1 and 2 example?

Of course if you precede it with "I suggested that...", "I thought that..." etc. it is quite different, because those verbs are in the past tense. On its own, You should do that when she came is nonsense.

@KateBunting what if I precede all my examples 3 4 5 and 6 with "I thought".?

[Sighs]. Yes, the same applies to all your examples where the tenses don't match.

Have you tried translating your examples 1, 3 and 5 in your mother tongue using a bilingual dictionary and an online translation software? Do they all make sense in your native language? No.1  "You should do" (advice referring either to the present of future) "when she came" (to do something when she arrived in the past). It's a silly sentence, you're not understanding (or you pretend not to)  the made up examples. There are many ways to say the same thing in English but this isn't the way to do it.

Then let's say No. 1, and 3, and 5 are nonsensical. They do not make sense. They are ungrammatical. The way you have constructed them are incorrect. They need to be revised and improved on.

@KateBunting pleaae once you have time answer if 3 with 4 and 5 with 6 have the same meaning and both are correct if preceded with something like "I thought". One more question if  you could answer too. Would you say these examples here are both correct with the same meaning "I thought you should be working" and "I thought you should have been working"?

Instead of inventing new sentences with the same words all the time, study the tenses. One by one, gradually progressing to more complex constructions. You really can't skip units or make one leap to another. Use an online translator to help you understand, you're not in an exam, they are useful tools. Write the sentence in your native language and get it translated into English. Don't do it the other way round because online translators do not correct mistakes. if your native language is rarely taught as second or third languages, e,g, Albanian or Slovenian then that is a problem.

You obviously didn't understand my last comment! To spell it out - 4 is OK as it is, but 3, 4, 5 and 6 are all (sort of) correct when preceded by 'I thought'. And, no, your new sentences don't mean the same. I thought [that] you should be working (at the time I was thinking it). I thought you should have been working (at an earlier time). PS Take Mari-Lou's advice!!

@KateBunting when we precede 1 and 2 with "I thought" they get different meaning. Something done after or before her arrival. As I understand it is not the case with the rest of my examples ,correct? When it comes to my new examples I think they have the same meaning when we add something to them like "I thought you should be working when she came and I thought you should have been working when she came", correct?

As you have been told repeatedly, (1) doesn't make sense unless you add something like "I suggested that...", "I thought that...". Adding these to (2) changes it from a blunt statement of what 'you' ought to have done to a milder suggestion or statement of what the speaker believed.  And, no, adding "I thought" to your new sentences does not make them mean the same because the tenses are different, as I explained.

@KateBunting I think that without preceding 2 means "during the time after she came it was my responsibility to do something". Although once preceded with "I thought" 1 gets the meaninng of 2 which wasn't preceded and preceded 2 means "it was your responsibilty to finish doing something before her arrival. Makes sense?

Makes no sense at all to me. (2) means either "You ought to have already done something by the time she arrived" or "You ought to have done it at the time of her arrival".

@KateBunting 1 I thought he should buy a car when we met  2 i thought he should have bought a car when we met. 1 during our meeting 2 either before or during?

Bad examples. You should have cleaned the house when she came (to visit). You should have offered her a cup of coffee when she came. As the system is asking us to avoid extended discussions, I am not going to continue this conversation.

Agree with Kate.
'Should' refers to the present or future.
'Should have' refers to the past.
'she came' is in the past and 'should' needs to reflect that, regardless of whether the 'it' action was meant to occur before or after her arrival.
Just as a side not, 'arrived' might be better here, as it is more specific in time and place. 'when she came' is somewhat ambiguous and could mean 'on her way here'. More context would help.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
